# Как правильно сохранить через PHP файл полученный через AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

Отправляю png файл через AJAX на PHP. `var_dump` в PHP показывает следщующее:

> string(1462575) "------WebKitFormBoundaryh7lE1zEduW95eI64 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="_клавиши_в_unity.png" Content-Type: image/png �PNG  IHDR�D....

При попытке просмотреть сохраненное изображение выдает ошибку о том, что файл поврежден.
Как правильно сохранить через PHP файл полученный через AJAX?

```
  <form>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit">
 </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var data;

    data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://abc-site.com/script.php',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data', 
        beforeSend: function (x) {
            if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                x.overrideMimeType("multipart/form-data");
            }
        },
        mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',

        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>

php


$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$name = explode('filename="', $content)[1];
$name = explode('"', $name)[0];
var_dump($content);
file_put_contents($name, $content);
```

Comment: Нащел рабочий код, но если кто знает почему не работал предыдущий - буду благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="res"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var data;

    data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://abc-site.com/script.php',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            //$('#res').append(data);
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>

<?php
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);
    }
```